# How can I calculate the eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, eigenvalue

```
import sympy
p1, p2, p3 = sympy.symbols('p1, p2, p3')

A  = sympy.Matrix([(p1+p2+p3) + 5, p2, p3],[p1, (p1+p2+p3) + 8, p3],[p1, p2, (p1+p2+p3) + 8] )

print(A.eigenvals())
```

I get an error of the values not being integers. What is the proper way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

You need another `[` and `]` inside the `Matrix`:

```
A  = Matrix([[(p1+p2+p3) + 5, p2, p3],[p1, (p1+p2+p3) + 8, p3],[p1, p2, (p1+p2+p3) + 8]])
```

will construct the matrix without raising an error.